# Where Has Our Recycle Bin Gone

Tags: sharepoint-online, recycle-bin

I have some users who have deleted documents. When I go to their Recycle Bin, a blank white page with nothing on it displays. How do we restore our recycle bin?

```
/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx
```

[image]

Comment: try to different browser?

Comment: bingo, wow amateur hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is browser issue, it is very common. couple of things you can try.

1. Clear the browser cache,
2. or completely logout from the account and close the browser
3. or try with different browser
4. or use the different computer

lastly, if none of the above works then you may contact the support.